# AWS Integration on Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I'm having problems setting up AWS Integration on a Kubernetes Cluster. I've already set the *kubernetes.io/cluster/clustername = owned* tag on all Instances, Subnets, VPC, and in a Single SG. I've also passed the *--cloud-provider=aws* flag to both API Server and Controller Manager, but the Controller Manager does not start.

Controller Manager Logs:

```
I0411 21:03:48.360194       1 aws.go:1026] Building AWS cloudprovider
I0411 21:03:48.360237       1 aws.go:988] Zone not specified in configuration file; querying AWS metadata service
F0411 21:03:48.363067       1 controllermanager.go:159] error building controller context: cloud provider could not be initialized: could not init cloud provider "aws": error finding instance i-0442e20b4a28b2274: "error listing AWS instances: \"NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.\\n\\tFor verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors\""
```

The Policy Attached to the Master Nodes is:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [ "ec2:*" ],
      "Resource": [ "*" ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [ "elasticloadbalancing:*" ],
      "Resource": [ "*" ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [ "route53:*" ],
      "Resource": [ "*" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Querying the AWS Metadata Service from a master via cURL returns proper credentials

Any help will be much appreciated!

P.S: I'm not using Kops or anything of that kind. I've set up the control components plane by myself.

Comment: are you sure that you have the correct tag?
we are using `"kubernetes.io/cluster/kubernetes" = "owned"` _(where the second string 'kubernetes' is the name of the actual kubernetes cluster)_

Comment: @DrGecko yes, I have all my resources tagged with "kubernetes.io/cluster/kubernetes/<clusterId>" = "owned". I've forgot to put the clusterId in the initial question. 
The value of clusterId can be any arbitrary value, right? I've never configured any "Cluster Name" on my Kubernetes cluster

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by passing the **--cloud-provider=aws** flag to the kubelets. I thought that wasn't needed on Master nodes.

Thanks!